# Permissions list for Forge servers

Tags: autodesk-forge

We are receiving data from Forge and I was wondering if it is possible to create some sort of permission list of forge servers. So basically we only want to receive data from either a specific IP adress or range. Is there any documentation about this?

Comment: For reference, are u using webhooks ?

Comment: For different Forge services you need to whitelist different IP address, so what Forge services do you use?

Comment: My question got answered:

Design Automation API for Revit
The Design Automation API for Revit imposes the following restrictions on your AppBundles, Activities and Workitems.

In order to process “onComplete” or “onProgress” callback behind a firewall, the following IPs need to be whitelisted for Revit :
3.213.115.148
3.212.238.83
3.208.45.222

Comment: Which IP needs to be whitelisted for the forge webhook data management API?